# Bases de datos relacionadas con hibernate

Tags: jsp, hibernate, servlets

Hice una migración a `hibernate` un crud y iba todo bien hasta que me faltó lo último la fase donde se relacionan dos tablas; pero el problema es que no se hacer la relación.

Hice una pequeña relación, pero no me funciona al momento de ejecutarlo con jsp solo me manda al servlet.

Este es el código que no me funciona. Ya hice el `SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE`:

```
 try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        Datos dato= new Datos();        
        Cuadro cuadro= new Cuadro(request.getParameter("titulo"),request.getParameter("imagen"));
        Lista lista= new Lista(cuadro,request.getParameter("miLista"));
        dato.guardar(lista);


       /*Constructor JDBC
        dato.ejecutar("Insert into lista (mi_lista, cu_id_fk)"
                + " values ('"+request.getParameter("mi_lista")+"',"
                        + " '"+request.getParameter("cu_id_fk")+"')");*/
        response.sendRedirect("administrador.jsp");   
    }
```

Actualización: todavía me sigue enviando a `servlet_lista`:

```
public class Servlet_Lista extends HttpServlet {


    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
           throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            Datos dato= new Datos();        
            Cuadro cuadro= new Cuadro(request.getParameter("titulo"),request.getParameter("imagen"));
            Lista lista= new Lista(cuadro,request.getParameter("miLista"));
            dato.guardar(lista);
           /*Constructor JDBC
            dato.ejecutar("Insert into lista (mi_lista, cu_id_fk)"
                    + " values ('"+request.getParameter("mi_lista")+"',"
                            + " '"+request.getParameter("cu_id_fk")+"')");*/
            response.sendRedirect("administrador.jsp");   
        }
//metodo guardar
 public void guardar(Object dato) {
        SessionFactory sesion = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session session;
        session = sesion.openSession();
        Transaction tra = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(dato);
        tra.commit();
        session.close();
    }

//ser modelo lista
public class Lista  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private Integer idLista;
     private String miLista;
     private Cuadro cuadro;

    public Lista() {
    }

    public Lista(Cuadro cuadro, String miLista) {
       this.cuadro = cuadro;
       this.miLista = miLista;
    }

    public Integer getIdLista() {
        return this.idLista;
    }

    public void setIdLista(Integer idLista) {
        this.idLista = idLista;
    }
    public Cuadro getCuadro() {
        return this.cuadro;
    }

    public void setCuadro(Cuadro cuadro) {
        this.cuadro = cuadro;
    }
    public String getMiLista() {
        return this.miLista;
    }

    public void setMiLista(String miLista) {
        this.miLista = miLista;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que Dato es una clase para el guardado de tus entidades en BD la forma sería la siguiente:

```
  try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            Datos dato= new Datos();        
            Cuadro cuadro= new Cuadro(request.getParameter("titulo"),request.getParameter("imagen"));
            Lista lista= new Lista(cuadro,request.getParameter("miLista"));
            dato.guardar(cuadro);
            dato.guardar(lista);

            response.sendRedirect("administrador.jsp"); 
    }
```

Recuerda que si quieres el guardado automático de las tablas relacionadas debes activar la función de **save en cascada**, esto se hace en el mapeo, tanto si lo haces con JPA o con el mapeo en XML.

Comment: mira el codigo pero no me da la funcion